# How to print the first two words in each sentence of a text

Tags: python, string

I have string with multiple sentences.

```
string1 = 'I am going to the shop. I would like some cheese! I am ready to go back home!'
```

How can i print the first two words of each sentence?
And the last two words of each sentence?

```
The first two words of each sentence are:
I am I would I am
The last two words of each sentence are:
the shop some cheese back home
```

Comment: Please describe the expected output for the given input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: To also print last two words of each sentence

```
import re
string1 = 'I am going to the shop. I would like some cheese! I am ready to go back home!'
split_list = re.split('[?.!]', string1)
for txt in split_list:
    print(txt.split()[:2],txt.split()[-2:] )
```

output

```
['I', 'am'] ['the', 'shop']
['I', 'would'] ['some', 'cheese']
['I', 'am'] ['back', 'home']
[] []
```

Comment: And of course for the last 2 words i replace with [-2:]. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
string1 = 'I am going to the shop. I would like some cheese! I am ready to go back home!'

# First two words
print('\nFirst two words')
print(' '.join(string1.split()[:2]))

# Last two words
print('\nLast two words')
print(' '.join(string1.split()[-2:]))

# First two and Last two with something inside...
print('\nFirst + something + last two words')
print(' '.join(string1.split()[:2]) + ' ...something... ' + ' '.join(string1.split()[-2:]))
```

Prints:

```
First two words
I am

Last two words
back home!

First + something + last two words
I am ...something... back home!
```

Comment: Yes, but i want to print the first 2 words and the last 2 words of each sentence like this:
The first two words of each sentence are : I am    I would     I am
The last two words of each sentence are: the shop   some cheese     back home

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a hundred ways to do this but the first one that comes to mind for me would be to use the strings split() method. This will split the string up into a list and each element will be a word

first_2_words = string1.split()[0:1]

this will split the string by the spaces and only grab the first 2 words